# Installing a theme on localhost, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: themes, installation, local-installation

I am using the LAMP stack, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version.

I installed WordPress and am trying to install a theme which I have in a `.zip` file

When I try to install the uploaded theme (where WP clearly says I can upload a `.zip` file if I have it), I keep getting the following error

> "Are you sure you want to do this?
>
> Please try again."

If I try again, the same story repeats.

Is there any way to overcome this issue. I have to be able to install this particular theme on `//localhost`.

www-data has privileges to create and delete on all sub directories in `/var/www/html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory `/wp-content/` of your local installations needs permission to create directory. It is necessary to upload the package and unpack.

### rights

Maybe this should helps, if the user is `www-data`.

`chown -R :www-data /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads`

`chown -R :www-data /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/upgrades`

Or full access to the wp-content directory `sudo chmod -R 777 wp-content/`

### php.ini

Also maybe the `php.ini` have not the right values to upload the package. Maybe you should try it with a small package. Or you change the php.ini of the LAMP, like the follow entries.

```
max_execution_time = 180
max_input_time = 600
post_max_size = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 256M
```

### helpful link

At least, [a link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574870/wordpress-cant-upload-files) to a helpful thread.

Comment: I set all the required permissions before installing WP.

Comment: Maybe you should enhance your question with this information, which rights have the directories, like `wp-content`.

Comment: All of them do. I set privileges to /var/www/html and all sub directories.

Comment: Maybe the php.ini have not the right values, see my edit above.